# add permission to model

Tags: python, django

I have two models, abstract user and admin, linked onetoonefield. I want to add permissions for admin. I registered in meta permissions, but they are not saved or created in the database. What do I need to do? When I call

```
admin.has_perm ('MoveOnApp.register_partner')
```

I get the error

```
'Admin' object has no attribute 'has_perm'
```

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Создал абстрактоного юзера от которого будут унаследованны остальные юзеры"""
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('phone number'),
        max_length=14,
        unique=True,
        help_text='Enter your phone number',
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=datetime.datetime.now())
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = BaseManager()
    is_superuser = None

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

class Admin(models.Model):
    """Создаю модель администратора, наследованную от AbstractUser"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(AbstractUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(
        _('company name'),
        max_length=150,
    )
    logo_url = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='img/logo'
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        _('first name'),
        max_length=50
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _('last name'),
        max_length=50,
    )
    # Флажок, такие права доступа рекомендует делать документация. Есть еще варианты но этот мне кажется самым удобным
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(
        _('admin status'),
        default=True
    )
    objects = BaseManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("register_partner", "Can register partner"),
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Admin` model is a basic model that has a user, but is not an user itself, to access its user-related properties you need to access the `user` attribute, like `admin.user.has_perm()`.

Comment: thanks, could you help me one more time? I checked and got that register_partner = false. But shouldn't it be True when creating an Admin?

Comment: When you add a permission in a model's meta class it only adds that permission to the list of permissions available to that model, so if you type in the shell `Permission.objects.filter(content_type__model='admin')` it's going to show up in the list.

Comment: In order to set this permission to the one-to-one user field, you need to add that newly created permission to the `user` object in your `Admin` model. That can be done when creating the admin, or afterwards, as it seems to be your case. Here's an example of programmatically adding user permissions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching